# How to setup logging file for cloud function in Google Cloud console?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I have deployed a Python 3.7 function to Google Cloud. The following statements set up the logging for the function. If I execute the function from command line, the recommender_logs.log file will be stored in the current working directory.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='recommender_logs.log',
                    filemode='w')
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

When I execute the function from the Google Cloud console, where do I need to set up this file, so that the function logs file will be stored in that? If I do not set up any path, where the file will be stored by default?

I can see the logs in **Logging** console, but apart from that is there a place to see this file, or only the cloud bucket is the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every function deployed in GCP runs in a separate container and if it needs to store any data then [it can only do so in the `/tmp` directory if the container it's running it](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system).

It doesn't matter if you deploy it from your compute, Cloud Shell or using API. [Your functions file system is isolated from any other function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#multiple_functions) or even another instance of itself.

You store your file in some persisten way you have to export it for exaple to a GCP bucket. [Have a look at this Stack answer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage) - it may be usefull to you.